# how to add content in Guest home using Webscript in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, web-scripting

As per documentation, there are APIs to access Companyhome, userHome objects etc. but there is none for guesthome object access.

Please share if there is an alternate way to access guesthome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just look it up by path?

Answer (score 1):

companyhome.childByNamePath("Guest Home");